# overflow: hidden doesn't work on a pseudo element

Tags: css, overflow, pseudo-element

I have a red square (`div`) and an orange bar as a pseudo element (`before`).
I want the part of the orange bar that goes outside the parent square hidden, so I used `overflow: hidden;` on the parent, but it doesn't work.

```css
.square {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(2em);
  width: 4.95em;
  height: .65em;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

The pseudo element is currently positioned relative to the root.

## The solution

You need to make it relative to `.square` instead by adding `position: relative;` to `.square`.

```css
.square {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
Position:relative;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(2em);
  width: 4.95em;
  height: .65em;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: this is not exactly the problem .. it can be positioned relatively to the root (viewport) and the overflow can work. replace position:relative with `transform: scale(1);` and you will see the same result .. it's about containing block more than positionning but positionning affect the containing block that's why it solves the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are right that this is about the containing block and that you can use `transform` to get the same result, but this positions the pseudo element relative to the `.square` not the root. https://jsfiddle.net/82dp1q3L/ and https://jsfiddle.net/82dp1q3L/1/ shows the difference in position when `tranform` is used and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/css/containing_block  confirms that this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `position: relative` to `.square`

```css
.square {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  position: relative; /* Added */
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(2em);
  width: 4.95em;
  height: .65em;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: `will consider body as relative` --> this is false, it will consider the first positoned ancestor and the body here is not positioned, so it will be the viewport

Comment: changed my comment @TemaniAfif

Comment: read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position for more precise description

Comment: sorry but this is also false `the pseudo will consider body as root.` .. check the duplicate question to get the exaclt explanation with correct wordings

Comment: removed everything @TemaniAfif

Comment: you can edit my answer @TemaniAfif

Comment: I already closed the question with the good duplicate, it shoud be enough ;)

Comment: that's great @TemaniAfif